# the difference between cardReference and token in parameter of Omnipay

Tags: omnipay

What is the difference  between cardReference and token in parameter of

[Omnipay](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay)

Answer (score 0):

cardReference should always be used by preference.  token can sometimes be used as a synonym for cardReference but often means something else, such as in the PayPal gateway "token" is used as an authentication parameter.